# Comparable type Sorting in a Vector int or String

Tags: java, sorting

In this I am trying to sort out the intV and stringV using this getSmallestValue method. Tried different ideas but does not seems to be working. Anyone have any bright ideas how to implement this getSmallestValue method?

```
public class test {

    public static Comparable getSmallestValue(Vector<Comparable> a) {
        Comparator com = Collections.reverseOrder();
        Collections.sort(a, com);
        return (Comparable) a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Comparable> intV = new Vector<Comparable>();
        intV.add(new Integer(-1));
        intV.add(new Integer(56));
        intV.add(new Integer(-100));
        int smallestInt = (Integer) getSmallestValue(intV);

        System.out.println(smallestInt);

        Vector<Comparable> stringV = new Vector<Comparable>();
        stringV.add("testing");
        stringV.add("Pti");
        stringV.add("semesterGoes");
        String smallestString = (String) getSmallestValue(stringV);

        System.out.println(smallestString);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you stepped through the code in a debugger, several mistakes would show up. ;)

Comment: Several warnings are coming up its true. But at this moment focus is to make this code work so after that can work out the rest easily. I know that the code is wrong but it does compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Your basic problem is that you have tried to turn a Vector into an Integer which you cannot do.

What is likely to be more useful is to use the first element of the vector.

I would suggest you

- use List instead of Vector.
- I wouldn't use manual wrapping
- define the getSmallestValue using generics to avoid confusion.

Here are two ways you could implement this method.

```
public static <N extends Comparable<N>> N getSmallestValue(List<N> a) {
    Collections.sort(a);
    return a.get(0);
}

public static <N extends Comparable<N>> N getSmallestValue2(List<N> a) {
    return Collections.min(a);
}

List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(-1, 56, -100);
int min = getSmallestValue(ints);
// or
int min = Collections.min(ints);
```

Comment: Yeah List is more easy way of doing it I did it using that. But I want to know is how to do it in a vector or an ArrayList.

Comment: `Vector` and `ArrayList` are both `List`  There is no difference.

Comment: Perfect answer you got it Peter. Thanks

Comment: This is all it needs.

    Collections.sort(a);
    return a.get(0);

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.min()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29).You can check out the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html) if you you want to know how it's implemented.

```
Vector<Integer> v=new Vector<Integer>();
v.add(22);v.add(33);
System.out.println(Collections.min(v));
```

Comment: Does not work still mate this error comes up                Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at test.getSmallestValue(test.java:17)
 at test.main(test.java:27)

Comment: Don't use getSmallestValue function instead use Collections.min

Comment: @Spiltter, that's becuase you are trying to turn a version a Vector into an Integer.  My guess is you are calling `min()` but ignoring the result??

Comment: You are right but if i use that then for String I have to use another way which is not what i want. Instead of doing that otherwise I would have used 

  
  Collections.sort(intV);
  System.out.println(intV);
  
  Collections.sort(stringV);
  System.out.println(stringV);

This way i dont need the method but its not what i am looking for this method should support any primitive type and get the smallest value thats the objective of this method

Comment: @Splitter:I didn't quite understand what your requirement is but for your information you cannot use primitive type with collection.You cannot write a generic function for primitive type.Atleast in Java this is not possible.Instead there are some api's like guava which support min function for primitive. Ints.min() function in guava is an example.